# Async Await - CancellationTokens when calling a SQL Server. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation-token

Is it good practice to be using cancellation tokens when making an asynchronous request to a SQL Server?

Lets just say we have a situation where we could end up with the SQL Server reporting an 'Operation Time out' failure.

Eventually SQL Server will return the exception to us.. and a Task from the thread pool that made receive a result containing the exception.

But would it be better if we where to defend against this by introducing a cancellation token with a shortened timeout limit.

My gut tells me that i should leave this up to the SQL Server to report any exceptions, but that could mean leaving the request hanging for minutes..

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: No need for a token. Just reconfigure the Timeout property of the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a time-out on the server side. ADO.NET already sets a timer that, when triggered, will abort the query.

Let me rephrase that: the *client* will ask the *server* to abort the query.

There's a more detailed explanation in [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/10/20/483015.aspx).